# How to access DSM quickly and securely from remote?

Tags: networking, 18.04, mount, ssh

I want to mount drives of my `Synology DS212j, DSM 6.2.1-23824 Update 4` from remote.

I used to do this on a windows machine by accessing my home network with a dyndns IP address. I know there are several ways to connect to the Synology, such as QuickConnect, SSH, VPN, WebDAV, and probably more.

I'd like to know which way is the fastest and safest way to do this on ubuntu 18.04 and how to do it exactly?

I've only found an [old](https://askubuntu.com/a/43070/897783) answer to this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can `ssh` into your NAS, you can also use Nautilus to view the files. Go to `sftp://username@yourserver.dyndns.com`. You will be asked for the `ssh` password.

Your home router needs to redirect the `ssh` port (default 22) to the NAS.

Security-wise that is as good as your NAS can withstand attacks on its `ssh` server.